# how to delete the contents in getExternalFilesDir(null) android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have saved some files by using the command:

```
File file = new File(cont.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
```

how can I delete all of the files I have saved? I need to clear the content of `cont.getExternalFilesDir(null)` directory.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete just a file you can do as told by Perroloco, but if you need do delete all content I think a OO approach will be better :)

First just build a method to delete files inside a directory recursively

```
private void deleteAllContent(File file,String... filename) {
    if (file.isDirectory())
        for (File child : file.listFiles())
            deleteAllContent(child);
    if(filename==null)
        file.delete();
    else
        for(String fn:filename)
            if(file.getName().equals(filename))
                file.delete(); 
}
```

Then you can just call your new method with your external files dir.

```
deleteAllContent(cont.getExternalFilesDir(null));
```

or

```
deleteAllContent(cont.getExternalFilesDir(null),"myfile1","myfile2","etc");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File(cont.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete delete any `Dir` with this:

```
private static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        if (children != null) {
            for (String child : children) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, child));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    } else if (dir != null && dir.isFile()) {
        return dir.delete();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
 try {
        File dir = this.getExternalFilesDir("yourdirname");
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```